# DRF Serialize 2 fields into array

Tags: django-rest-framework

DRF v3.12.4

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    field_0 = models.CharField()
    field_1 = models.FloatField()
    field_2 = models.FloatField()
```

Have such a model, and I need to serialize it (read-only) in such way:

```
{ "field_0": "FIELD0", "arr": [ 1.0, 2.0 ]}
```

For now, I make the next solution:

```
class BSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        return [data.field_1, data.field_2]
class ASerilizer(serializers.Serializer):
    arr = BSerializer(source='*')
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ['field_0', 'arr']
```

It's work, but I also use drf-spectacular and of course, it can't analyze the overriding method. I'm trying @extend_schema_serializer on BSerilizer, but it does not work.

Is it possible without overriding the to_representation method?

So, the question is it possible for such a case to use a serializer without overriding the to_representation method, ListSerializer for example? Or maybe someone knows why @extend_schema_serializer does not work?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want just use `arr` field as a read_only field, you can use serializer's SerializerMethodField:-

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ASerilizer(serializers.Serializer):
    arr = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ['field_0', 'arr']

    def get_arr(self, instance):
        return [instance.field_1, instance.field_2]
```

For more information you can refer from here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield